# Deploying Rails to a cluster on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, load-balancing

I have setup a load balancer and an auto scaling group of EC2 instances on AWS to host a Rails site. This all works fine most of the time.

My deployment script deploys new versions of the app to each instance one at a time.

During a deployment it can happen that a page is served by an instance with the new version of the app and some assets are served by an instance with the old version (or vice versa) resulting in pages with missing images, css or javascript.

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

I have thought of the following options but none are ideal:

- Scale down to one server during deployments. Then I can't deploy during peak times.
- Disable Rails asset fingerprinting. Will cause caching issues.
- Deploy to each instance simultaneously. Increases risk and I don't know how to do it anyway.
- Enable sticky sessions on the load balancer. This is not recommended but seems to be the best option I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into blue/green deployment, where you stand up and deploy to a new cluster and then switch traffic to it via DNS. Doing so would prevent the version mismatches you describe, as well as give you an easy and immediate rollback option. It'd be more complicated, slower, and (slightly) more expensive, however.

There are plenty of resources on the web, and there's an Amazon-specific page [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html), although it uses Elastic Beanstalk and therefore wouldn't be immediately applicable for you.